In WebRTC, both peers seem using different routes to send data
I am using different WebRTC SDKs for my devices.
One peer is an android app with native WebRTC SDK (libjingle_peerconnection), while the other is a Linux device with AmazonKvsWebrtc SDK.
When the peerconnection is connected, it is observed both peers are using different routes to send data.
Android App:
Switching selected connection due to: candidate pair state changed.
Switching selected connection due to: candidate pair state changed.
New selected connection: Conn[34116200:0:Net[rmnet_data3:10.101.81.x/29:Cellular:id=24]:/ZRDDEcP:1:0:relay:udp:120.48.x.x:50818->KiixbVmC:1:2130706431:prflx:udp:220.248.x.x:40183|CRWS|S|0|0|179053269526511614|77]
Network route was changed.

Linux Device:
08-06 10:40:25.072 606 668 D IceAgent:handleStunPacket(): received candidate with USE_CANDIDATE flag, local candidate type srflx(yhqUqPr+O:nbNZpB2oP).
Remote Candidate type: srflx
Local Candidate type: srflx

It can be seen the Android App has selected the relay:prflx candidate pair, whereas the Linux device has selected the srflx:srflx pair.
Further investigation revealed that, the Linux device received multiple STUN messages with USE_CANDIDATE flag from different candidates. However, these subsequent messages were ignored or pruned bacause the srflx:srflx candidate pair had already been selected for data transmission.
Before proceeding with any further attempts, I would like to know if this phenomenon is normal in WebRTC, or if it could be due to a logging error or an implementation issue within one of the WebRTC SDKs.
